# How to remove white bottom border in splash screen in android

Tags: android, splash-screen

I want to remove white bottom border in this splash screen. I change many layout relative to linear but nothing changed.Anyone can help me how i remove this white border:

My splash_screen.xml:-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">

<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />   </RelativeLayout>
```

My Image:-
[image]

Comment: Set android:scaleType="fitXY".

Comment: I do this but no effort

Comment: set the background color to back of your parent relative layout..

Comment: ScaleType fitXY should do that, also remove that adjustViewBounds

Comment: Set background to your `Relative layout` itself.why your going to an image view for that which is redundant ?

Comment: i tried all your suggestion but no effort on my result

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:background="#000000">

<View android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:src="@drawable/a"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:adjustViewBounds="false"
    android:scaleType="centerCrop"
    />   </RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: now its time to check the image of splash. or try to set it as background not resource.

Comment: I think your image has that white border

Comment: Ohh sry yes i changed my image and problem is solved.
Thanks all of you for my help

Comment: can you get me your contact mail id for future help

Comment: sorry... but you can post your problem here.. some one will definitely solve it.. may be m not available every time..but #stackOverFlow is.

Answer (score 1):

Try this,

**activity_splash.xml**

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/splash_screen" >

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: No effort on my result

Comment: please, check your image that has a white border?